# Meaning of a formula for the $y$-intercept?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, determinant, intuition

Suppose a line goes through the points $A = (x_1, y_1)$ and $B = (x_2, y_2)$. One can easily check (as I did today while doodling) that
$$
b = - \frac{x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1}{x_2 - x_1}
$$
where $b$ is the y-coordinate of the y-intercept. This can be written more suggestively as
$$
b = -\frac{\det(A, B)}{\Delta x} \label{b}\tag{1}
$$
The presence of $\det(A,B)$ suggests a geometrical interpretation, but I couldn't think of one.
This reminds me of Cramer's Rule, but I couldn't make that connection explicit either.

Can anyone give an interpretation for equation \ref{b}?

Answer (score 3):

Basically you are using the fact that the area enclosed by three collinear points is zero

$A(x_1, y_1), B(x_2, y_x), C(0,b)$ are the three points, then

$$\begin{vmatrix}x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\ x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\0  & b & 1\end{vmatrix} = 0$$

Now expand along the bottom row to get the equation you have

Answer (score 1):

Re-write the equation as
$b (x_2 - x_1)= (x_2 y_1) – (x_1 y_2)$

[image]
$x_2 y_1 = (2)+(3)+(4)+(5)+(6)$

$x_1 y_2 = (1) + (2)+(3)+(4)$

Added: A is a point on the diagonal of the rectangle involving (1), (2), (3), (5), and the part in white. Point A, together with the added lines, will divide the whole rectangle into four parts (namely (1), (2) + (3), (5) and the part in white). A theorem in geometry (its proof is skipped) says (1) is equal to (5) in area.

RHS$ = (5)+(6) – (1)= (6) = b(x_2 - x_1) = $ LHS

Comment: Why does (5) + (6) - (1) = (6)?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins See added for an explanation.

Comment: I see. I think I can picture the similarity argument that would establish the result.

Comment: That fact is true for all parallelograms, not just a rectangle.

Comment: Could you share the code (gnuplot?) for this beautiful diagram?

Comment: @147pm There involves no codes. Just draw direcrtly in Geogebra.